# Import stat.h using LuaJIT

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I am writing a Lua application, and I am trying to access the values of the `S_IWUSR` constant inside the `stat.h` header file using the [FFI library](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) of LuaJIT.

How can I include `stat.h` in my Lua code so I can access the constant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ffi.cdef` you can load most C code in the **FFI C namespace**, but there's no preprocessor so far, so you should use enums for constant values.

In my `sys/stat.h` `S_IWUSR` is defined as followed:

```
#define _S_IWRITE 0x0080
...
#define _S_IWUSR    _S_IWRITE
...
#define S_IWUSR     _S_IWUSR
```

Example with LuaJIT:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef([[
    enum{S_IWUSR = 0x0080};
]])

print(ffi.C.S_IWUSR) -- 128
```

There's also the way with `static const` variables to add a type.

```
static const int S_IWUSR = 0x0080;
```

**BUT** you have to care not to redefine! Remember: there's just one FFI instance per Lua state, `require("ffi")` doesn't make a new one. It's recommend to put C definitions in a module and let the Lua package system manage loading them just once.